# Data driven protractor tests

Tags: database, protractor

I wanted to know the best way to do the following:

Before running Protractor tests

- Insert data into tables from two DBs (PostGres)

After running Protractor tests

- Clear the data inserted above

I am a newbie at this and didnt find a straight forward answer so far

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside the protractor conf.js you can require js files that will setup the data either adding it to a file or the brower.env object.

```
const testConfig = (new (require('../testConfig.js'))(__dirname, "../config.json")).getConfig();
```

You can also use this to setup the config object and several methods that protractor call.s onPrepare, beforeLaunch, afterLaunch

You should be able to clear data in the afterLaunch method.